# How can I embed rendering result in a JavaScript asset file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, erb

I have a partial file `/app/views/shared/_foo.html.slim`, and I want to embed the result of rendering it in a JavaScript file located in the `/app/assets/javascript` directory using ERB. (The result is an HTML string, and I will use that to create a jQuery object.)

I tried the following:

#### application.js.erb

```
...
var foo = $('<%=render partial: "shared/foo"%>');
...
```

but it raised an error: `` undefined method `abstract?' ``, so I tried to load some view helpers:

```
...
<%Sprockets::Context.send :include, ActionView::Helpers%>
var foo = $('<%=render partial: "shared/foo"%>');
...
```

but it raises the same error. I am not sure if it it the correct way to keep adding the required files in this way, and if it is, what files I should load.

What is the correct way to render partial files within JavaScript ERB files?

Comment: Please include the error message and stack trace in your questions. It is near impossible to help debug remotely without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the modern, and the correct, way to do it is to use the class method `render` defined on the controller classes. I was able to do it with the following code:

```
...
var foo = $('<%=ApplicationController.render partial: "shared/foo"%>');
...
```